# Как добавить(прибавить) значение в поле MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Как добавить в поле БД значение, не перезаписывая его ?
Например, добавить в поле `words` БД `users` значения (сначала одно, потом второе и пр.), **НО** только где пользователя зовут `Vasya`.
Как пример (конечно, не рабочий=), лишь для понимания задачи):

```
INSERT INTO users(words) VALUES('freezer') WHERE username='Vasya';
```

Потом добавить слово `морковь`, `авто`, `рыба` и пр., чтобы в поле `words` сохранились все эти слова.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это неправильный синтакс

Comment: @user7103883 вы хотите в одно поле одной строки поместить несколько значений?

Comment: @Regent, да, всё верно. Это словарь, в общем =) Т.е. какие слова пользователь добавил себе

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE username=Vasya' at line 1`

Comment: @user7103883 правильнее будет создать таблицу `UsersWords`, в которой будут поля `userId` и `word`.

Comment: Ну собсн вам надо иметь другую таблицу `words` на которую надо будет ссылаться из `users` иначе ничего не получится... Иначе как отделить одного васю в таблице от другого

Comment: @Regent, это да. Но вопрос всё же актуален.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Даже если и будет эта таблица, то как же я, всё же, смогу это осуществить?

Comment: @user7103883 в одну ячейку можно затолкать несколько значений только через сепаратор. То есть чтобы значением было, например? `freezer морковь` или `freezer,морковь`. Но работать с таким полем, скажем прямо, неудобно.

Comment: @Regent, как же лучше сделать?

Comment: @user7103883 вы сможете сделать `INSERT INTO UsersWords(userId, word) VALUES (104, 'freezer'), (104, 'морковь');` по user id этого самого `Vasya`.

Comment: @user7103883 банально `INSERT INTO words (userId, word) VALUES(1, 'freezer'), (1,'морковь'), (1,'авто'), (1,'рыба')`  где 1 - идентификатор юзера из таблицы `users` .... этот идентификатор вы каким-либо образом получать должны.

Comment: @user7103883 лучше, повторюсь, сделать отдельной таблицей, не создавая себе проблем из-за заталкивания нескольких значений в одну ячейку.

Comment: @Regent, Спасибо, теперь понял суть!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо!

Comment: А добавление выполняет не INSERT, а UPDATE: `UPDATE users SET words = CONCAT(words, ' ещё слова')` WHERE username='Vasya';`